# Tkinter button command to switch classes with frames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to `Tkinter` and I am having some trouble getting my button command to switch to a different class.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.gotoMainMenu)
        button.pack()

    def gotoMainMenu(self):
        root2=tk.Toplevel(self)
        myGUI=MainMenu(root2)

    def finish(self):
        self.parent.destroy()

class MainMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1")
        button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is the current code I am working on. I have tried looking examples, but I can't seem to figure it out. I currently receive an attribute error. "AttributeError: MainApplication instance has no attribute 'gotoMainMenu'." Also, any errors you find or advice you have is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You simply forgot to pack your `MainMenu` frame. Add the following line to the end of your `MainMenu` class's constructor:

```
self.pack()
```

Comment: I have packed my MainMenu, but I still receive an attribute error. "AttributeError: MainApplication instance has no attribute 'gotoMainMenu'." Am I properly switching between classes?

Comment: @Joel I guess you have missed some `self.` somewhere...Check the code in your question above.